# Returning XPATH response as a python dictionary

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, unicode-string

Scrapy noob here. I am extracting an href 'rel'attribute which looks like the following:

```
rel=""prodimage":"image_link","intermediatezoomimage":"image_link","fullimage":"image_link""
```

This can be seen as a dict like structure within the attribute.

My main goal is to obtain the image url against 'fullimage'. Hence, I want to store the response as a python dictionary.
However, Xpath returns a unicode "list" ( Not just a string but a list!) with one item ( the whole rel contents as one item)

```
res = response.xpath('//*[@id="detail_product"]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/@rel').extract()
print res

[u'"prodimage":"image_link", "intermediatezoomimage":"image_link", "fullimage":"image_link"']

type(res)

type 'list'
```

How do I convert the content of 'res' into something like a python dictionary ( with separated out items as list items, not just one whole item) so that I can grab individual components from the structure within 'rel'.

I hope I am clear. Thank you!

Comment: Only values for attributes of an XML tag  in the XPATH make sense for a dictionary, you can always grab that using RE. BTW you are losing the order of items because of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The XPATH response above is basically a list with ONE item in unicode.
Convert the respective items into strings ( using x.encode('ascii') )
and then form a string representation of a dict. In my case I had to append and prepend the string (the rel contents) with curly braces. Thats all!

Then convert that string representation of a dict into an actual dict using the method mentioned in the link below.

[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary)